# Correct syntax for @font-face in Stylus / using stylus-font-face npm

Tags: css, node.js, fonts, stylus

I need to get the following CSS output from Stylus (bit of a backward way to do it but Stylus will make so many other parts of this project easier). I've tried a fair few things but can't get it to compile, and when it says that it has compiled nothing shows for this part of the output. I haven't had any joy implementing [stylus-font-face - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-font-face) as the documentation there doesn't seem to show an example of the Stylus needed. Here's the output I need, and any help is really appreciated.

```css
@font-face {
 font-family:'apercu-regular';
 src: url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.svg#apercu-regular') format('svg');
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
 unicode-range: U+0020-25CA;
}
```

Comment: Version of Stylus? I've just copy-pasted your example to CodePen (Stylus 0.50.0) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjWKzm (click to "View Compiled" to see compiled CSS) and all works fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for that; I was trying to use Stylus in its minimal syntax (no curly braces, colons etc.) but I couldn't get the above code to compile like that. It hadn't occurred to me that I could work around this by just writing normal CSS and making use of Stylus' variables and other features that way.

Answer (score 6):

I've worked out how to get it to compile correctly in minimal syntax Stylus (I wanted to use Jeet, Boy and Rupture so I had to do it that way). Hope this helps someone.

```
@font-face
    font-family 'apercu-regular'
    src url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.eot')
    src url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/apercu-regular/Apercu_gdi.svg#apercu-regular') format('svg')
    font-weight 400
    font-style normal
    font-stretch normal`
```

Comment: If this multiple src/url example was given at stylus-lang.com, it would have saved me a lot of time. Thank you!!